# Run a shell command through Perl in a specific terminal

Tags: linux, perl, shell, command-line

First off, I am pretty new to Perl so I may be missing something obvious. This is not the typical "I want to run a shell command through Perl" question.

I don't want to capture all of the shell output. I have a program/script that intelligently writes to the terminal. I didn't write it and don't know how it all works, but it seems to move the view to the appropriate place after printing some initialization, then erase previous terminal output and write over it (updates) until it finally completes. I would like to call this from my perl script rather than printing everything to a file to grab it after, since printing to a file does not keep the intelligence of the printout.

All I need to do is:

1. open an xterm in my perl script
2. make a system call in **that** terminal
3. have that terminal stay up until I manually exit it

Can I do this in perl?

Thanks.

Comment: From the commandline, I'd open it like `xterm -hold -e programname`, I assume you can do this from perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
system 'xterm', '-hold', '-e', $program;
```

where `$program` is the terminal-aware program you want to run.

**`-hold`** causes xterm to stay open after the program exits, waiting for you to close it manually.

**`-e`** specifies the program or command line to run.  It and its argument must appear last on the xterm command line.

Comment: I'd like to suggest `system("xterm", "-hold", "-e", $program)` or `system "xterm -hold -e " . quotemeta($program);`, so that malicious `$program` values like `$program="echo; rm -rf /"` won't mess you up...

Comment: Agreed, Mr. Mørch.  I had only rendered `$program` as a variable to indicate it should be replaced by whatever Stuart wanted and not thinking about user input, but quoting them separately is still a better practice.  Answer edited.

Comment: Please expand on the difference.

Comment: Stuart, when the whole command line is passed as one argument (as I originally had it, `"xterm -hold -e $program"`), Perl invokes a shell to process the command.  That means any shell metacharacters will be expanded, which could be dangerous if `$program` could somehow be supplied by a different user than the one running the xterm.  It's a bit unlikely in this case, since the OP is likely just defining `$program` earlier in the file.  But it's still a good practice to pass commands to `system` as separate arguments (which doesn't invoke a shell) unless you really need the shell parsing.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this by example :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict; use warnings;
use autodie;

open my $term, '| xterm -hold -e $(</dev/stdin)';
foreach my $dir (qw|/etc /usr /home|) {
    print $term "ls $dir\n"; # do anything else you'd like than "ls $dir" here
}
close $term;
```

Comment: this works, but does it have any advantages over ajk's answer which is more straightforward?

Comment: It makes things simpler to use in a loop by example or to reuse multiple times.

Comment: Added `foreach` example : as you can see, calling `$term` filehandle is sufficient without the need to type again `xterm ...`